GCP Terraform CICD pipeline getting failed in GitHub
`Hi folks,
I am facing issue in my cicd pipline on GCP cloud  which i set in github with terraform workflow.
bellow error I am getting.
Run terraform plan -input=false
/home/runner/work/_temp/86fbf72d-0d05-43a8-9ea3-6c50d50b0210/terraform-bin plan -input=false
╷
│ Error: Required plugins are not installed
│ 
│ The installed provider plugins are not consistent with the packages
│ selected in the dependency lock file:
│   - registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google: there is no package for registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google 5.24.0 cached in .terraform/providers
│ 
│ Terraform uses external plugins to integrate with a variety of different
│ infrastructure services. To download the plugins required for this
│ configuration, run:
│   terraform init`


I tried these steps to resolve, but no luck*

terraform init -upgrade
Remove-Item -Path ".terraform/providers" -Recurse -Force
terraform init


What errors do terraform init give?

terraform init is not giving any error, i have setu CICD , so in stage terraform plan , I am facing error  Error: Required plugins are not installed
